# Docker certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I just installed docker for the first time and when the default virtualbox or 'docker-machine'(not sure what it is called I run into this error:

This is an excerpt

```
Checking connection to Docker...
Error creating machine: Error checking the host: Error checking and/or regenerat
ing the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.99.1
01:2376": x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]
'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop runni
ng containers.
```

I tried using the `docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]` command and it seemed to work no errors were raised at least. Only when I attempted to run docker's hello world command this is the result I got.

```
docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.39/c
ontainers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file s
pecified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must
 be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon
 is not running.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I searched up similar errors and found a few case where creating a new virtualbox/docker-machine(still don't know what its called) solved it but the same error that appeared with the default box showed up.

```
Error creating machine: Error checking the host: Error checking and/or regenerat
ing the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.99.1
01:2376": x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]
```

Afterwards I gave the `docker-machine ls` command a try in order to see if I could find something helpful. This is the output.

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DO
CKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           Un
known   Unable to query docker version: Get https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.15/ve
rsion: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
first     -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           Un
known   Unable to query docker version: Get https://192.168.99.101:2376/v1.15/ve
rsion: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: can you add more details about what is your setup and how did you install docker and the docker-machine?

Comment: I used DockerToolbox installer and my setup was just the custom setup. Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4eee

Comment: Please specify if you are running this on Linux or Windows and if Windows which version of it.

Answer (score 8):

Try `docker-machine regenerate-certs --client-certs`.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the `--client-certs`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your command prompt run:

```
docker-machine ls
```

it will return

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
<name>    <status> <driver>     <state>   <url>                       <swarm> <docker>  <errors>
```

get the `<name>` of the machine you want to run (if it's the first time you are running docker, then you have only one machine running and its name is `default`, in this example I will call it `<name>`)

then run:

```
docker-machine kill <name>
docker-machine create <name>
docker-machine env <name>
```

The last command will output more lines, copy the last one, in my case it was like this:

```
# eval $("C:\my\path\to\docker-machine.exe" env <name>)
```

then paste it in the command prompt **without the `#`** and run it, the problem should be fixed now.

You can check it by running `docker-machine ls`, if the problem is fixed, you should see no more messages under the `ERROR` column.

Furthermore, it is possible that the lines

```
docker-machine kill <name>
docker-machine create <name>
```

are not required if you have only one docker-machine existing and its `<name>` is `default`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
use this setting:
{
"insecure-registries":[
"0.0.0.0/0"
]
}

then restart service:
service docker restart

and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nope, this is a docker machine certificate, not a registry certificate. There is no docker service where they're running the commands.