# How to update kubernetes certificates with docker desktop on MacOS

Tags: docker, macos, kubernetes, x509certificate, docker-desktop

I am using kubernetes with docker desktop on MacOS Monterey.
I have problem with starting kubernetes, because 1 year passed and my kubernetes certificates are invalid.

How can I renew them ?

Error message:

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/version": EOF
```

I tried to install `kubeadm` but I think it is only suitable if I use `minikube`.

Edit:
I am using Mac with M1 chip.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new set of [certificates](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/macfaqs/#how-do-i-add-tls-certificates) and keys in order to update the certificates used by Docker Desktop for MacOS. After that, you will need to add the new certificates and keys to the Kubernetes configuration file. Create a certificate signing request (CSR) first, then use the CSR to create new certificates and keys. The Kubernetes configuration file needs to be updated to point to the new certificates and keys after they have been obtained in the appropriate directory structure. Finally, in order for the brand-new certificates and keys to take effect, you will need to restart your Kubernetes cluster.

Using the minikube command-line tool.Use the minikube delete command to get rid of the existing cluster is the first step in updating the certificates. The minikube start command can be used to create a new cluster with the updated certificates after the cluster has been deleted. Finally, save the cluster configuration file with the most recent [certificates](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/untrusted_certs/) by employing the minikube get-kube-config command.

Check for the kubernetes version if you are using an older version upgrade it to the latest version,the Kubernetes version can be upgraded after a Docker Desktop update. However, when a new Kubernetes version is added to Docker Desktop, the user needs to reset its current cluster in order to use the newest version.

Comment: I am using docker desktop as a virtualisation environment. Is your comment valid for my case ?

Comment: In your case you can use minikube command-line tool

Comment: But I am using M1 chip and that's why I am using docker desktop as virutalisation env. Sorry, I forgot to mention the architecure type.

Comment: Try `docker-machine regenerate-certs --client-certs` taken from this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65045766/), check it for reference.